# Determining "days" in python when the timedelta.days is less than one

Tags: python, date, datetime, timedelta

sorry in advance if this is dense. I am trying to find the days since I last posted a tweet. The problem I am running into is when the dates are different, e.g., today and yesterday, but not enough hours have passed to be a full "day."

```
# "created_at" is part of the Twitter API, returned as UTC time. The 
# timedelta here is to account for the fact I am on the west coast, USA 
lastTweetAt =  result.created_at + timedelta(hours=-8)

# get local time
rightNow = datetime.now()

# subtract the two datetimes (which gives me a timedelta)
dt = rightNow - lastTweetAt

# print the number of days difference
print dt.days
```

The problem is that if I posted a tweet at say 5 PM yesterday and am running the script at 8 AM today, only 15 hours have passed, which is 0 days. But obviously I want to say it's been 1 day since my last tweet if it was yesterday. And a kludge of adding "+1" isn't going to help because if I have tweeted today, I want the result to be 0.

Is there a better approach than using timedelta to get the difference?

---

**Solution** 
*provided by Matti Lyra*

The answer is to call .date() on the datetimes so they are converted to coarser date objects (without timestamps).  The correct code looks like:

```
# "created_at" is part of the Twitter API, returned as UTC time.
# the -8 timedelta is to account for me being on the west coast, USA
lastTweetAt =  result.created_at + timedelta(hours=-8)

# get UTC time for right now
rightNow = datetime.now()

# truncate the datetimes to date objects (which have dates, but no timestamp)
# and subtract them (which gives me a timedelta)
dt = rightNow.date() - lastTweetAt.date()

# print the number of days difference
print dt.days
```

Comment: What's wrong with looking at `dt.seconds` then?

Comment: try `rightNow = datetime.utcnow()` to avoid managing the timezone manually (assuming you have the correct local time/timezone settings)

Comment: .seconds doesn't help because I want to know the _days_ between tweets. If I post a tweet at 11 PM and run the script at 1 AM (2 hours later) I want "1" to be returned. But if I post a tweet at 1 AM and run the script at 3 AM, I want a "0" returned. .seconds is going to have the same problem as .days.

utcnow() is fine, but whether I convert the Tweet's time to my local time or my local time to UTC is just six of one, a half dozen of the other.

Comment: Thinking about this more TokenMacGuy, I *should* convert Twitter's UTC time into my time because the difference in execution vs. post should be relative to me.  When I post a tweet at 5 PM Pacific time, Twitter returns a response with a datetime of 1 AM UTC the next day.  If I run the script at 1 AM Pacific, then it would calc the difference between 1 AM UTC (tweet post) and 9 AM UTC (script execution), which leads to a return of 0 days difference. But I want it to say 1 day because I am running it at 1 AM local time (after midnight) and the last tweet was at 5 PM the previous day.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `datetime.date()` to compare the two dates (note: NOT dates with times), this truncates the `datetime` to have an resolution of days not hours.

```
...
# subtract the two datetimes (which gives me a timedelta)
dt = rightNow.date() - lastTweetAt.date()
...
```

The docs are always your friend

http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime#datetime.datetime.date

Comment: Gah, I was in the middle of posting exactly this... +1

Comment: exactly what it was trying to remember... long day. +1

Comment: Ahhhhh - there we go. I was so concerned about the UTC vs. local issue I didn't consider - and believe I looked at the docs, I swear! - converting back to a coarser granularity once I had the correct dates. Thank you!!

Answer (score 13):

How about dealing just with the "date" part of your datetimes?

The part after outputing "0" in the following code:

```
>>> a = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> b = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(hours=20)
>>> (a-b).days
0
>>> b.date() - a.date()
datetime.timedelta(-1)
>>> (b.date() - a.date()).days
-1
```